# Java Static Factory Class like Scala

Tags: java, scala

I have written a sample code in Scala and I need to convert to Java, but I am kinda confused how I can have this pattern in Java,

In Scala I have:

```
object Writer {
  val options = new scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[String, String]
  def a: Option[String] = options.get("a")
  def b: Option[String] = options.get("b")
  def c: Option[String] = options.get("c")

  def option(key: String, value: String): Writer.type = {
    options += (key -> value)
    this
  }

  def write() ={
    println(a.getOrElse("Z"))
    println(b.getOrElse("Z"))
    println(c.getOrElse("Z"))
  }

}
```

Which I can run with or without passing the option(s):

```
object Run {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    Writer
      .write()

    Writer
      .option("a", "A")
      .option("b", "B")
      .option("c", "C")
      .write()
  }

}
```

How can I convert this to Java?

Comment: What have you tried? What problems did you encounter? What did you do to try and solve them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scala object is like singleton object in Java:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Optional;

public class Writer {

    private Writer(){}

    private static Writer instance;

    public static Writer getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new Writer();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public Map<String, String> options = new HashMap<>();

    public Optional<String> a() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(options.get("a"));
    }

    public Optional<String> b() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(options.get("b"));
    }

    public Optional<String> c() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(options.get("c"));
    }

    public Writer option(String key, String value) {
        options.put(key, value);
        return this;
    }

    public void write() {
        System.out.println(a().orElse("Z"));
        System.out.println(b().orElse("Z"));
        System.out.println(c().orElse("Z"));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Writer.getInstance()
                .option("a", "A")
                .option("b", "B")
                .option("c", "C")
                .write();

        Writer.getInstance().write(); // same output as above
    }
}
```